# Listing all Network Connections, then managing one

Tags: c++, windows, networking, network-programming

I'm developing an application in C++ for Windows 7, that sets up a TFTP server to communicate to an embedded device. The device is supposed to be connected directly to the Ethernet port, and it expects a TFTP server on 192.168.1.19 static address.

To simplify user experience, I want the following scenario:

- present a list of all network connections registered in the system to the user (same list as in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections")
- allow to choose one connection
- memorize its IPv4 configuration
- set IPv4 configuration to 192.168.1.19 and 255.255.255.0
- after TFTP job done, restore original IPv4 configuration

The problem I encountered is a mix of the following:

- when no Ethernet cable plugged, neither of GetAdaptersInfo, GetInterfaceInfo, GetAdaptersAddresses list the connection I'm interested in;
- even if I get that connection, I'm not sure which API to use to set DHCP on/off, static IP, network mask.
- I tried using netsh, and it works fine, but I don't want to run it from my app, because I don't want to deal with non-English characters in the connection names.

Suggestions welcome,
Thanks!

===== edit #1

Tried WMI query "Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter Where NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection'" -- no IP address in the feedback, although I can see it in the Control Panel connection properties.

Queries involving Win32_NetworkConnection don't return anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

- "Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter Where PhysicalAdapter='True' AND AdapterTypeID=0" query to list adapters/connection names/guid - works pretty good
- registry to read configuration via guid
- netsh to do configuration via connection name. Yes, I had much fun with locales.

I frankly didn't find a more reliable way to work with disconnected connections. Hope this helps. If anyone has better solutions - I'd be glad to see them!